# How to set variable in emacs in batch mode

Tags: batch-file, emacs, elisp, org-mode

I am a total emacs/lisp newbie, just trying to export my todo's to ics.  In my init file I have (setq org-calendar-icalendar-todo t), and when I export within emacs with C-c C-e I, then I do get the todos exported in the .ics files.

However I want to do this in a batch file.  I have run emacs --batch -eval "(org-export-icalendar-all-agenda-files)", but it doesn't seem to pick up the org-calendar-icalendar-todo variable in the init file or produce the output files.

How can I make this happen on the command line?

Comment: Can't you just add that `setq` sexp to your `-eval`? I.e., `emacs --batch -eval "(progn (setq org-calendar-icalendar-todo t) (org-export-icalendar-all-agenda-files))"` (or the other order, if that is appropriate -- I do not use Org).

Comment: Probably with the batch mode you load an older version of org.

Answer (score 1):

With minimal movements you can do this:

```
emacs --batch -l ~/.emacs --eval "(org-export-icalendar-all-agenda-files)"
```

If loading the whole config is too much for you, just create a separate file
`~/foo.el` with your preferred config and replace `~/.emacs` with `~/foo.el` in the
command above.